# Is '=' antisymmetric?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

I know that an antisymmetric relation must meet the following condition: `If x <=y and y<=x then x=y`. That being said, can one consider `x=x` to be antisymmetric?

P.S.: Something tells me that the answer is right under my eyes, but I just cannot seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: draw directed graph of a simple set (like A={1,2,3,-1,-2}) on '=' relation .It will be easy to understand antisymmetric relation .

Comment: Equality is perhaps the weakest of all relations, since it has all the properties: It is basically a purely reflexive relation ($x$ only has a relation with $x$). In that sense it is the only relation which is both symmetric and anti-symmetric.

Comment: When dealing with relations, I always ask for examples of relations that are both symmetric and antisymmetric, or both reflexive (for all $x$, $(x,x)\in R$) and antireflexive (for all $x$, $(x,x)\notin R$). Some of the students are able to find an example for the latter question, which is quite nice, in my opinion.

Comment: OK then ... what relations are BOTH symmetric and antisymmetric?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A relation $R$ is antisymmetric if the following statement is true for all $x$ and $y$:

> If $xRy$ and $yRx$, then $x=y$.

To test whether this is true when $R$ is $=$, you just plug in $=$ for $R$.  So the question is, is the following true for all $x$ and $y$?

> If $x=y$ and $y=x$, then $x=y$.

Do you now see how to answer the question?

Comment: I see. It is as if I let y=x then x=x (obvious). I really should have seen that right away.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, yes it is.

The definition is as you put it.

Or in other words, an antisymmetic relation is one where there is no distinct pair a, b ( a$\ne$ b) where aRb and bRa.  As there are no distinct pair a $\ne$ b where a = b and b = a, equality is by definition antisymmetric.